# How to uninstall the Oracle DB Client when $ORACLE_HOME has spaces in the path?

Tags: perl

I have a bunch of Windows machines that need to have the Oracle Database Client removed and reinstalled on them.  The problem I'm having is that whoever installed them used `C:\Program Files\Oracle\Database Client\21.0.0` as the `$ORACLE_HOME` directory instead of the default `C:\app`.  Oracle's built-in deinstaller can't handle file paths with spaces in them.

The deinstall a simple batch file that calls a couple Perl scripts with `$ORACLE_HOME`as an argument, so I just decided to invoke the `bootstrap.pl` manually, and here's what I get:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Oracle\Database Client\21.0.0\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:\Program Files\Oracle\Database Client\21.0.0\deinstall\bootstrap.pl" 1 ^"C:\Program Files\Oracle\Database Client\21.0.0^"

18 File(s) copied
Invalid number of parameters
Bootstrap Failed. at C:\Program Files\Oracle\Database Client\21.0.0\deinstall\bootstrap.pl line 148
```

*Note that the carets (^) in the command line above are required to escape the double quotes. Otherwise, you wind up with `C:\Program` as an argument.

Here's the relevant lines of code from the `bootstrap.pl` script:

```
  my @sourceDirs = ($dest.$dirSep.'deinstall',$ORACLE_HOME.$dirSep.'oui',$ORACLE_HOME.$dirSep.'perl',$ORACLE_HOME.$dirSep.'jdk',$ORACLE_HOME.$dirSep.'oracle_common');
   if($giHomeCleanFound == 0)
   {
   
   if ( $^O eq "MSWin32" ) {
      system("xcopy /y/s/i/e/q $sourceDirs[0] $dest") == 0 or die "Bootstrap Failed.";
      print $ORACLE_HOME.$dirSep.'oui';   #<-- I added this statement to see what the sting looks like 
      system("xcopy /y/s/i/e/q $sourceDirs[1] $dest\\oui") == 0 or die "Bootstrap Failed.";   #<-- This is the line where it fails
      system("xcopy /y/s/i/e/q $sourceDirs[2] $dest\\perl") == 0 or die "Bootstrap Failed.";
      system("xcopy /y/s/i/e/q $sourceDirs[3] $dest\\jdk") == 0 or die "Bootstrap Failed."; 
      if ($nextGen eq "true") {
        system("xcopy /y/s/i/e/q $sourceDirs[4] $dest\\oracle_common") == 0 or die "Bootstrap Failed.";
      } 
   }
```

So really, the Perl scripts are just sending the work back out to the command line.  It's basically a vicious circle of double quotes not being escaped properly.  This is just one block of one of the Perl scripts, so I'm sure this kind of code is everywhere in it.  I'd really like to not have to rewrite Oracle's scripts for them. I tried scripting Oracle's manual removal instructions once upon a time and it did not go well.

Is there a way to escape the double quotes from the command line in such a way that they get escaped properly when passed back to the command line from the Perl script?

Alternatively is there a better tool out there that can remove the client cleanly?

Comment: Workaround, use the dir's short name (probably `C:\Progra~1`) instead of `C:\Program Files`

Comment: Bad answer: But double quotes around it. You'll need to escape them since they're in double quotes.

Comment: Good answer: Use Win32::ShellQuote

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to uninstall this stuff, it might not be worth fixing the perl. You can see what it's trying to do and just do it manually. Then you get on with life. Sometimes I also find it easier to just take the space out of the path when it's a one off thing that doesn't need future attention.

Now, on to some interesting points.

I don't play with Oracle, so I'm merely responding to the general idea. And, if that bootstrap.pl is provided by Oracle, maybe you can win a [bug bounty](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/security-practices/assurance/vulnerability/reporting.html) (if they even do that).

In general, don't make command strings from user input (or external sources) then give that big string to `system`. Sometimes we talk about this because of various security considerations. For example, if someone can mess around with the various inputs that decide the paths that end up in `@sourcedirs`, they might be able to execute other DOS commands in that `system`. I cover this sort of thing in the Security chapter in [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org) and plenty of people have written about this elsewhere, so we'll let that go. [perlsec](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec) is a good read too.

Just as a bonus, there's a few other weird things here in case you are playing perl bar trivia.

- `File::Spec::catfile` can make paths without the `$dirsep` stuff.
- The directory separator is in the perl Config.

```
$ perl -V:path_sep
path_sep=';'

$ perl -MConfig -le "print $Config{path_sep}"
;
```

We need to talk about spaces in paths more than we do. Somehow the idea of spaces in paths have not caught up to the practice of programming. We all know that there can be spaces until we write some code.

@ikegami already pointed out [Win32::Shellquote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Shellquote). I also have the [Perl.com article "Quoting the Shell"](https://www.perl.com/article/quoting-the-shell/):

```
use Win32::ShellQuote qw(:all);
system quote_system( qw(xcopy /y/s/i/e/q), $sourceDirs[0], $dest );
```

There are various other ways to quote the Win32 shell command depending on what you are trying to do.